# Switching between 2 nvidia GPUs

Tags: nvidia, gpu

On Ubuntu 16.04. I have 2 Nvidia GPU's. How can I choose which one is being used for OpenGL rendering? 
lspci detects both GPU's, and both show up in Nvidia settings. When I run something like Unigen-Heavan, GPU 0 is used. How can I make it use GPU 1?
(Only have one monitor)
Thanks

---

Still looking for a better answer to actually switch GPU 0 and GPU 1, but what ended up working was turning off GPU 0 (the internal) in BIOS, connecting the external GPU, and connecting the screen to the external GPU. This actually improves performance slightly, I need to change the cable connected to the monitor.

Comment: Not a solution, but have you considered switching the GPUs in the computer?

Comment: Unfortunately not possible, 
One is the laptops desecrate GPU and another is an external. 
I am trying to use the external